# Oracle syntax for subselect in FROM clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, inline-view

According to [Using Subqueries](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries007.htm) Oracle SQL accepts a subquery in the from-clause of a select statement, like

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT a FROM b );
```

However, looking at the [SELECT documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm), I see no possibility to get to select/subquery in the from clause (e.g. from the rules `table_reference` or `join_clause`).

Am I missing something here, is this part of the SQL grammar documented elsewhere? Or is this another incomplete part of the documentation?

Comment: It's called inline view in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries007.htm#SQLRF52357

Comment: The ANSI SQL term is _derived table_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the documentation you linked, you can see that `table_reference` can be a `query_table_expression` which can be a `( subquery )`.

Comment: totally overlooked that, thank you (and the other commenters too)!

Answer (score 3):

Oracle syntax diagrams are pretty thorough:

The names you are looking for are:

- table-reference --> query-table_expression
- query-table-expression --> subquery

It is a bit confusing because of the optional `lateral`.

I do wonder if the lateral is allowed everywhere that expression is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Every derived table must have its own alias.

You can use something like

```
  SELECT * FROM b
  WHERE a >
     (SELECT a FROM b
      WHERE a='India')
```

Or simply use

```
SELECT * FROM b
  WHERE (SELECT a FROM b)
```

But in this way, you will have more than 1 row.If you will not use **Where** clause

Comment: This is not true for Oracle. In Oracle you can have a derived table without giving it an alias name (which is quite convenient at times.) Your second query is invalid in Oracle, because Oracle's SQL doesn't know a boolean type. To be valid in other DBMS the subquery would have to return no more than one record and column `a` would have to be boolean.